Trouble Accessing Jupyter Etc. through Anaconda
Disclaimer: I want to make clear I am a total laymen when it comes to this. I just search answers to my problem, use chatgpt when needed etc. So if you know the answer, please explain as if you are talking to an idiot lol. Thank you.
I have downloaded Anaconda on my firm computer. When I click to open jupyter it asks me each time: "select an app to open this .html file" (dont usually get this prompt on other computers if relevant)
I select google and It says the attached:

Immediate Problem:
I took a look in the search bar and its trying to access via this
Users/[User name]/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-4012-open.html
I took a look at the file location and found a html title "jpsever-4240-open"
I assume this must be a part of the problem as anaconda is trying to access a different file that no longer exists.
Does anyone know how to resolve this?
Additional Notes for Context:
I had initially downloaded Anaconda via the web before but it was not working as I did not know I need to do some token verification for Zscalar which my firm uses.
Because I don't know what I am doing I initially assumed that it could be fixed if I downloaded python via the company portal (using their python download), so I uninstalled and deleted all anaconda files and downloaded the company version.
The problem still remained so I contacted IT and got the verification problem resolved.
As I still wanted to use anaconda, and the latest python version, I tried uninstalling the company python but needed admin privileges to uninstall
After contacting IT, the guy I worked with installed another version of python from the web without telling me and then downloaded anaconda thereafter (not sure if there would be a conflict there)
Which brings me to where I am at now, where jupyter does not work.
More (Less related):
This may be another problem down the road, but I tried opening Spyder via anaconda to see if that worked and it seems to be fine, but it is accessing anaconda through the Admin User and not my User (When I look at the top left of spyder it says C:\Users\[Admin User]\.spyder-py3\temp.py
Not sure If I will run into a problem down the road there, but figure I'd mention it.
Thank you.

I'd suggest looking at the anaconda navigator.
When you installed Anaconda, it should've came with a program called Anaconda Navigator. It's really great for managing python virtual environments (essentially projects for python). It'll solve a lot of the organization issues you have going on. If anaconda navigator hasn't been downloaded, you probably have to install Anaconda again. Anaconda Download
You don't need to install or reinstall python over and over again. Just use Anaconda Navigator to manage your python projects.
